# In Postgres, is it performance critical to define low cardinality column as int and not text?

Tags: postgresql, indexing

I have a column with 4 options.
The column is define as text.
The table is big table 100 millions of record and keep going.
The table use as report table.
The index on the table is - provider_id,date,enum_field.

I wonder if i should change the enum_filed from text to int and how much this is performance critical.

Using postgres 9.1

Table:
provider_report:
  id bigserial NOT NULL,
  provider_id bigint,
  date timestamp without time zone,
  enum_field character varying,
  ....

Index:
provider_id,date,enum_field

Comment: Give us the full definition of the table. It is hard to tell anything for your current question.

Comment: @IgorRomanchenko i edit with partial table def.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR version: worrying about this is probably not worth your time.

Long version:

There is an enum type in Postgres:

```
create type myenum as enum('foo', 'bar');
```

There are pros and cons related to using it vs a varchar or an integer field. Mostly pros imho.

In terms of size, it's stored as an `oid`, so `int32` type. This makes it smaller than a varchar populated with typical values (e.g. `'draft'`, `'published'`, `'pending'`, `'completed'`, whatever your enum is about), and the same size as an `int` type. If you've very few values, a `smallint` / `int16` will be admittedly be smaller. Some of your performance change will come from there (smaller vs larger field, i.e. mostly negligible).

Validation is possible in each case, be it through the built-in catalog lookup for the `enum`, or a check constraint or a foreign key for a `varchar` or an `int`. Some of your performance change will come from there, and it'll probably not be worth your time either.

Another benefit of the enum type, is that it is ordered. In the above example, `'foo'::myenum < 'bar'::myenum'`, making it possible to `order by enumcol`. To achieve the same using a `varchar` or an `int`, you'll need a separate table with a `sortidx` column or something... In this case, the enum can yield an enormous benefit if you ever want to order by your enum's values. This brings us to (imho) the only gotcha, which is related to how the enum type is stored in the catalog...

Internally, each enum's value carries an `oid`, and the latter are stored *as is* within the table. So it's technically an int32. When you create the enum type, its values are stored *in the correct order* within the catalog. In the above example, `'foo'` would have an `oid` lower than `'bar'`. This makes it very efficient for Postgres to order by an enum's value, since it amounts to sorting `int32` values.

When you `ALTER` your enum, however, you may end up in a situation where you change that order. For instance, imagine you alter the above enum in such a way that `myenum` is now `('foo', 'baz', 'bar')`. For reasons tied to efficiency, Postgres does not assign a new `oid` for existing values and rewrite the tables that use them, let alone invalidate cached query plans that use them. What it does instead, is populate a separate field in the the `pg_catalog`, so as to make it yield the correct sort order. From that point forward, ordering by the enum field requires an extra lookup, which de facto amounts to joining the table with a separate values table that carries a `sortidx` field -- much like you would do with a `varchar` or an `int` if you ever wanted to sort them.

This is usually fine and perfectly acceptable. Occasionally, it's not. When not there is a solution: alter the tables with the enum type, and change their values to varchar. Also locate and adjust functions and triggers that make use of it as you do. Then drop the type entirely, and then recreate it to get fresh oid values. And finally alter the tables back to where they were, and readjust the functions and triggers. Not trivial, but certainly feasible.

Comment: The table has milions of records and getting bigger, so it hard to test (i will not do this kind of change on big production data unless i know that it realy effective). I always thought that index int is much better than text indexing.

Comment: You assessment is accurate: int is indeed faster for btree indexes, because a < b for ints is merely about comparing bits, whereas 'a' < 'b' depends on a heap of other things. And it's typically smaller unless your enum is stored as a one byte `char`, so you'll be more likely to have it lying around in memory. With a billion entries, the difference might begin to add up. Whether it's worth the downtime related to rewriting the table is another question altogether.

Answer (score 0):

It will be best to define an enum_field as [`ENUM`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-enum.html) type. It will take minimal space and check, which values are allowed.

As for performance: the only reliable way if it really affects performance - to test it (with proper set of correct tests). My guess - the difference will be less than 5%.

And if you really want to change the table - don't forget to `VACUUM` it after the change.